# how to get the value of hyperlink into the action class

Tags: struts2-jquery

I want to get hyperlink attribute value in action class in struts.is there any way to get the value of hyperlink attribute value in action class. i have 4 link, if i clicked on any link, invoked single action class.

```
<s:url  id="ajax1"  action="totcal" />
<sj:a value="b1" name="b1" href="%{ajax1}" targets="progressbarchange1" >
BreakFast  
</sj:a>
```

In above code  `value="b1"` retrive in action class.
please help

Comment: That makes no sense. To get a value in an action class you have to *send* a value.